# How can I get two variables from a string with Regex

Tags: regex, variables, capture

I have the following string that I need to extract two variables from with Regex.  I've been looking at tutorials, but not getting the results I need.  Can anyone help?

AWS-010062347904-uptree-base-prod-admin

I need the 12 digits between the first two hyphens as accountid (ie. 010062347904)
and everything after the 2nd hyphen as role (ie. uptree-base-prod-admin)

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?:[^-]*-)(?<accountId>\d{12})(?:[^-]*-)(?<role>.*)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HGDpjL/1)

Answer (score 0):

From your pattern in the comments `^AWS\-(?<accountid>\d+)` you are matching `AWS-` from the start `^` of the string and after that you are using a named capturing group `accountId` to capture 1+ times a digit.

You could get that accountId by referring to that named capturing group. To capture the role you can use another named capturing group:

`^AWS-(?<accountId>\d+)-(?<role>.*)$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ww6cAx/1)

If you want the digits after the first hyphen without taking into account what is at the start of the string you could use a negated character class `[^-]*` at the start matching 0+ times not a hyphen:

```
^[^-]*-(?<accountId>\d+)-(?<role>.*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ww6cAx/2)